# dataframe concatenating with indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dataframe that reads from a file

the next step I do is to break dataset into 2 datasets df_LastYear & df_ThisYear

*Note : that Index is not continuous missing 2 & 6*

```
      ID  AdmissionAge
0     14            68
1     22            86
3     78            40
4    124            45
5    128            35
7    148            92
8    183            71
9    185            98
10   219            79
```

after applying some predictive models I get results of predictive values y_ThisYear

```
     Prediction
0   2.400000e+01
1   1.400000e+01
2   1.000000e+00
3   2.096032e+09
4   2.000000e+00
5  -7.395179e+11
6   6.159412e+06
7   5.592327e+07
8   5.303477e+08
9   5.500000e+00
10  6.500000e+00
```

I am trying to concat both datasets df_ThisYear and y_ThisYear into one dataset

but I always get these results

```
       ID  AdmissionAge    Prediction
0    14.0          68.0  2.400000e+01
1    22.0          86.0  1.400000e+01
2     NaN           NaN  1.000000e+00
3    78.0          40.0  2.096032e+09
4   124.0          45.0  2.000000e+00
5   128.0          35.0 -7.395179e+11
6     NaN           NaN  6.159412e+06
7   148.0          92.0  5.592327e+07
8   183.0          71.0  5.303477e+08
9   185.0          98.0  5.500000e+00
10  219.0          79.0  6.500000e+00
```

There are NaNs which did not exist before

I found that these NaNs are belonging to the index which was not included in df_ThisYear

Therefore I try reset index so I get continuous Indices

I used

df_ThisYear.reset_index(drop=True)

but still getting same indices

How to fix this problem so I can concatenate df_ThisYear with y_ThisYear correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because y_ThisYear  has different index than df_ThisYear

When I joined both using

```
df_ThisYear.join(y_ThisYear  )
```

it started to match each number it its matching index

I know this is right if indices are actually represent the same record i.e. index 7 in df_ThisYear value is matching y_ThisYear  index 7 too

In my case I just want to match first record in y_ThisYear  to the first in df_ThisYear regardless of their index number

I found this code that does that.

```
df_ThisYear = pd.concat([df_ThisYear.reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(y_ThisYear)], axis=1)
```

Thanks for everyone helped with the answer

Answer (score 2):

Then you just need `join`

```
df.join(Y)
     ID  AdmissionAge    Prediction
0    14            68  2.400000e+01
1    22            86  1.400000e+01
3    78            40  2.096032e+09
4   124            45  2.000000e+00
5   128            35 -7.395179e+11
7   148            92  5.592327e+07
8   183            71  5.303477e+08
9   185            98  5.500000e+00
10  219            79  6.500000e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really excited about using `concat`, you can provide 'inner' to the how argument:

```
pd.concat([df_ThisYear, y_ThisYear], axis=1, join='inner')
```

This returns

```
Out[6]: 
     ID  AdmissionAge    Prediction
0    14            68  2.400000e+01
1    22            86  1.400000e+01
3    78            40  2.096032e+09
4   124            45  2.000000e+00
5   128            35 -7.395179e+11
7   148            92  5.592327e+07
8   183            71  5.303477e+08
9   185            98  5.500000e+00
10  219            79  6.500000e+00
```